# javascript class variable inside function says undefined ES6

Tags: javascript, es6-class

```
class Auto {
  printauto() {
    var type = "2 wheeler";
    var color = "green";
    console.log("Car type is="+this.type+" "+" and color="+this.color);
 }
}

var a = new Auto();
a.printauto();
```

why is output undefined?

Car type is=undefined  and color=undefined

Comment: Because a variable is not the same as a property. `var type` and `this.type` are two different things.

Comment: `this.type` is `undefined` because you never set `this.type` to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching a variable to the class context doesn't happen just by declaring it. You have to be explicit:

```js
class Auto {
  printauto() {
    this.type = "2 wheeler"; // explicitly attach to `this`
    this.color = "green";    // same here
    console.log("Car type is="+this.type+" "+" and color="+this.color);
 }
}

new Auto().printauto();
```

The constructor is usually the best place for such initialization:

```js
class Auto {
  constructor() {
    this.type = "2 wheeler"; // explicitly attach to `this`
    this.color = "green";    // same here
  }
  printauto() {
    console.log("Car type is="+this.type+" "+" and color="+this.color);
 }
}

new Auto().printauto();
```

Answer (score 1):

This refer to class and you don't have color and type declared in your class. The color and are scoped inside your printauto method. either you declare them in your class or just do this

```
console.log("Car type is="+type+" "+" and color="+color);
```

By declaring in class

```
class Auto {
    this.type = "2 wheeler";
    this.color = "green";

    printauto() {
        console.log("Car type is=" + this.type + " " + " and color=" + this.color);
    }
}
var a = new Auto();
a.printauto();
```

Comment: thank you and why i get error for below code:- 

class Auto {
  var type = "2 wheeler";
  var color = "green";
  printauto() {    
    console.log("Car type is="+type+" "+" and color="+color);
 }
}

var a = new Auto();
a.printauto();

Comment: you don't use var inside your class just variable name with public or private 

class Auto {
    type = "2 wheeler";
    color = "green";

    printauto() {
        console.log("Car type is=" + this.type + " " + " and color=" + this.color);
    }
}
var a = new Auto();
a.printauto();

Comment: That syntax is [still not part of the language](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/). Properties cannot be put on classes at this time.

Comment: @Yogi i was bit wrong, i mixed it up with type script you have to use this inside your class for declare variables. See my updated answer. it will be supported to declare properties inside class without this key word.

Answer (score 0):

As described by Felix King in comment, variable `a` is not the same as properties of class `Auto`

```js
class Auto {
  printauto() {
    var type = "2 wheeler";
    var color = "green";
    console.log("Car type is="+ type+" "+" and color="+color);
 }
}

var a = new Auto();
a.printauto();
```